# How to connect additional drives to HBA controller?

Tags: raid, sata, sas, raid-z

I have a HBA 330 IT controller which has 2x4 12 Gbit/s SAS (or 6 Gbit/s SATA) ports, available through two SFF-8643 mini-SAS connectors. Though it has only 8 ports, it can aparently support up to 32 drives. I wonder, how would I connect more than 8 drives?

I use it together with WD Red 8TB (cmr) drives for a FreeNas RAID-Z2.

Currently I have 4 of these SATA drives attached at one of the two mini-SAS connectors.

now I would like o add 8 more drives (for a total of 12 drives).

I have an 8-drive enclosure that has two backplanes, each of which can be attached through one SFF-8087 connector.

So, here are my questions:

- how do I split from one 4-port SFF-8643 connector (on the conroller side) to two 4-port SFF-8087 connectors (one for each backplane)?
- since the SAS connectors provide 12 Gbit/s per port and my SATA drives only use 6 Gbit/s per port, can I expect for these 8 SATA drives sitting on one SFF-8643 connector to perform equally well as the other 4 drives sitting on the oher SFF-8643 connector?
- is it okay to place all 12 drives into the same RAID-Z2 array, even though 4 of them are directly connected to one of the (4-port) connectors, while the other 8 are connected through some sort of splitter to the other (4-port) connector?
- is this kosher?

Comment: I’ll just leave some advice here: Don’t create a single RAIDZ2 vdev that large. The resilver times will be insane. However, since you cannot expand a RAIDZ2, your 4-drive RAIDZ2 will stay as-is anyway.

Comment: I intend to backup the current array, create a new 12drive one and then restore.
what do you mean by insane. Days? months? years?

Comment: Also, doesn't resilver time just depend on the drive size (or how much data actually is used on that one drive) rather than the size of the vdev?